# SwiftUI - Watch App reachability & scenePhase showing opposite of what it should

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I have a watch kit app and an ios app, and when the watch is open/active and i launch the ios app, everything works great. However, when the watch app goes into the background, I get output from the terminal that the watchSession isReachable is true, and the scenePhase of my watch app is active. When I wake my watch up and open the app, isReachable is set to false, and my scenePhase is set to inactive (and all my interactive messaging stops working).

I'm using a boilerplate watch session manager code, this is how I'm checking if my session is valid:

```
class WatchSessionManager: NSObject {

var validSession: WCSession? {

        
        #if os(iOS)
        if let session = session, session.isPaired && session.isWatchAppInstalled {
            return session
        }
        return nil
        #elseif os(watchOS)
        return session
        #endif
    }
}
```

then in my watch app @main View:

```
.onAppear {
guard let watchSession = WatchSessionManager.shared.validSession else { return }
if scenePhase != .background && watchSession.isReachable {
            WatchDataDistribution().getAllDataFromPhone() //does interactive messaging
        }
```

and this is how I am checking the scene phase (in my @main WatchApp struct):

```
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
```

It's reporting the opposite of what is actually happening and I don't know why.